# Display WebGrid columns in default order

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, webgrid

I have multiple tables I am using a WebGrid to display. The WebGrid displays my columns alphabetically, but I want them displayed the way they are being passed to the WebGrid. (The order that it is in the database.) I can not specify what columns to order by because I have a list of tables I do a foreach on to populate the WebGrids and the tables have different columns in them.

**View:**

```
 @{
 foreach (var item in ViewBag.GenericTable) {
 var grid = new WebGrid(item);
           @grid.GetHtml(
                  headerStyle: "table table-bordered",
                  tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",
                  alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                  selectedRowStyle: "table-inverse"                
             );
           }
```

**Controller:**

```
 Object[] tableList = { dataPersonal, dataTraining, dataPersonHistory, dataLogs, dataTracking, dataUsageStats  };

 ViewBag.GenericTable = tableList.ToList();
```

Comment: Use TemplateFields perhaps? I cannot suggest something more detailed as your question lacks code.

Comment: I have added code to show my process.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://forums.asp.net/t/1926105.aspx?My+web+grid+columns+are+being+sorted+alphabetically+where+is+that+set+

Comment: VDWWD This would work, but I would have to list every column name in every table to get the default column order I desire, which I would like to avoid.